# QML dynamic list of widgets

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt-quick

I have a QStringList property, and I basically want to turn that into a group of radio buttons dynamically, so that when the QStringList property changes the number of buttons and their labels is automatically updated.

I can *sort of* do it with a ListView, but it has problems:

1. It's not really a desktop widget so you have all the mobile bounciness.
2. I can't get the ListView selection and the radio button checks to interact nicely.

Here's my attempt anyway. I'd ideally like to do it without a ListView though:

```
        ListView {
            id: myList
            orientation: ListView.Horizontal

            ExclusiveGroup {
                id: myListExclusiveGroup
            }

            Component {
                id: myDelegate
                RadioButton {
                    text: modelData
                    onCheckedChanged: {
                        if (checked)
                            myList.currentIndex = index
                    }
                    exclusiveGroup: myListExclusiveGroup
                }
            }

            model: myListOfStrings
            delegate: myDelegate
            focus: true
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `Repeater` based on a `ListModel` which you  update when your list of buttons changes?

Comment: Aha, `Repeater` was exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Glad I could help, I was working on an example but you beat me to it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to koopajah, I changed it to use `Repeater` and it works now. Note that it seems `Repeater` adds everything to the *end* of its parent's children, which means you can't rely on its position in a layout - you have to put it inside another layout, for example like this:

```
        ExclusiveGroup {
            id: myListExclusiveGroup
        }
        RowLayout {
            Repeater {
                id: myList

                RadioButton {
                    text: modelData
                    exclusiveGroup: myListExclusiveGroup
                }

                model: myListOfStrings
                focus: true
            }
        }
```